# How to do in order to tweet to the right e-mail address as the current Bluemix ID

Tags: twitter, ibm-cloud, node-red

We are building Bluemix service using Node-RED. The last node "Tweet out" is showing Error in the attached screen shot.
We are thinking that the service is automatically connected to the old e-mail address of Twitter account that was used as Bluemix ID before at the API application authentication.
Could you please tell me how we should do in order to tweet to the right e-mail address of Twitter account that is the current Bluemix ID.

[image: Bluemix Flow]

Comment: I modified the application according to #1 answer and found that "Delay" is valid only for the first input. And I want to insert wait for the specified time between each output and to specify the number of times to tweet out. Could you please give me additional information to implement it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with which user is being used, the 187 error<sup>1</sup> code is because you are sending the exact same tweet over and over again.

Twitter won't let you just post the same message every second.

You should probably include the RBE (report by exception) or a delay node (in rate limit mode) between the "danger" function and the twitter output node.

[1] https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer ! I will try it soon.